# Problem of loading external page into div by using jquery

Tags: jquery, search, post, html

I want to create the search page that search the history of log file. Because of limitation of display area, I want the user to limit the date range of the log file before displaying the search result.

I have created Datepickers "from" and "to" which will give the input the date range. The button will be the submit this date range.

```
<Form action="/" id="searchDate">
From: <input type="text" name="from" id="datepickerFrom"> 
To: <input type="text" name="to" id="datepickerTo">
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</Form>
```

and  here is script...

```
<script>
// attach a submit handler to the form
$("#searchDate").submit(function(event) {
  // stop form from submitting normally
  event.preventDefault(); 
  var eID = $("#userID").val();
  // get some values from elements on the page:
  var $form = $( this ),
  termFrom = $form.find( 'input[name="from"]' ).val(),
  termTo = $form.find( 'input[name="to"]' ).val(),
  url = $form.attr( 'action' );
  // Send the data using post and put the results in a div
  $.post("/home/", function(data){
  $( "#result" ).load("/search/"); //.html(termFrom+" "+termTo);
  }

);
});
</script>
```

It was working if I use $( "#result" ).html(termFrom+" "+termTo); statement, but .html it is accept only string of html. I want to post the date into external page to perform the query and load that external page into div of search box page, so I use .load("/home/search/"). I just want to test loading the external page without passing post value, but it is not working. Why .load() is not working in this case?

Thank in advance...

Comment: first of all, its `form` not Form.

Comment: changing Form to form the result is still the same...

Comment: what happens if you go to `/search` or whatever url you are calling with `.load` in the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you jsut want to test it without sending any post data then just use:

```
$.post("/home/search", function(data){

  $( "#result" ).html(data);

});
```

when you wnt to actually send the values you need to do:

```
$.post("/home/search",{"termFrom": termFrom, "termTo": termTo}, function(data){
  $( "#result" ).html(data);
});
```

Comment: It is working properly if I am using ".html(str)", but if I am using ".load(url)" it is not working

Comment: Why are you trying to use load? All load does is use `.html()` to drop in the response html into the target... the same thign you are doing manually in your success callback with post. Do you see any errors in your javascript console?

Comment: I'm using django. I cannot use .html() which return only html. I want it to call my controller which is python npt html.

Comment: I realize youre using Django, but its not clear to me why youre trying to use both `load` from within the callback to `$.post` why dont you just call the url for the controller that provides the html you want to render in one or the other - what are you trying to use `load` from within the callback to `post`? I must be missing something in what youre actually trying to do but i cant figure it out :-)

Comment: I asked my colleague to look at it. She did exactly same as you told me to. Refreshing for a few time, and then it works.  Thank you very much...

Answer (score 2):

if I understand 'external' correctly you get cross domain ajax policy problem - read more about it on http://usejquery.com/posts/9/the-jquery-cross-domain-ajax-guide

Comment: From the definition of "Same Origin" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy   Are "/home" and "/home/search" considered under the same protocol and host?

Comment: Actually, I am using django. It runs the same server same host same port. I change the url to "/search/" the result is still the same.. this external means another page that using the same setting.

Answer (score 0):

Did you miss a quotation mark in the following code?

```
 $.post("/home/, function(data){
  $( "#result" ).load("/home/search/"); //.html(termFrom+" "+termTo);
  }
```

Would this cause the problem?

Comment: it was my mistake. Actually, I already fix this point but the result still the same.